# Django Query, find most common value for field on a many to many relation

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

Given these models (where a Restaurant has many *Pizzas* and Pizzas have many *Toppings*)

```
class Restraunt(Model)

class Topping(Model):
  name = Charfield()

class Pizza(Model):
  in_resteraunt = ForeignKey(Resteraunt) 
  toppings = ManyToMany(topping, related_name='on_pizza')
```

I'm trying to figure out how: Given a Restaurant, across all its Pizzas, **what is the most common topping?**

One thing I came up with is something like this (where R = the restaurant)

```
Topping.objects.filter(on_pizza__restaurant=R).annotate(the_count=Count('on_pizza')).order_by('-the_count')[0]
```

The problem here is that I'm not sure if the on_pizza is unique to the Restaurant object, basically a topping object can be on a pizza at multiple restaurants I need it to be unique.
Here I'm starting from the Topping, is there a way I could start from a queryset of pizzas?

I've looked into subquery expressions but don't really see how to implement

Comment: Well it will only take into account `Topping`s for that restaurant, and also filter the pizzas. So yes this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem here is that I'm not sure if the `on_pizza` is unique to the `Restaurant` object, basically a topping object can be on a pizza at multiple restaurants I need it to be unique.

The query is **correct**. You *filter* on the restaurant, so that means that in the `Count`, it will only count `Pizza`s that are for the restaurant *`R`*. So this will indeed calculate the most common topping for pizzas made in restaurant `R`.

The query will thus look like:

```
SELECT topping.*, COUNT(pizza.pk)
FROM topping
LEFT OUTER JOIN pizza_toppings ON pizza_toppings.topping_id = topping.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN pizza ON pizza.id = pizza_toppings.pizza_id
WHERE pizza.restaurant_id = id_of_r
GROUP BY topping.pk
ORDER BY COUNT(pizza.pk)
LIMIT 1
```